# Adding bash script to disable Nvidia graphic card at startup?

Tags: nvidia, bash, startup

I've found the way to disable my hybrid card GT 540M on Asus K53SV at: 
https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

That's great, but I need those commands to be executed automatically at startup. So I followed the [instructions here](http://www.aoddy.com/2009/03/02/how-to-start-a-script-by-root-permission-at-boot-time-on-ubuntu-server-810/).

Actually, I copy the bash file instead of creating link in `/etc/init.d/`

However, it doesn't work at all. My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start my own acpi_call"
cd
cd acpi_call
insmod acpi_call.ko
./test_off.sh
echo "finished.Thank you"
```

I tried both using "sudo insmod" and "insmod" only but still no effect.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9763/init-d-script-startup-problems/9767#9767) ? It's a previous post here in AU to run init.d scripts on startup. It says look at `man insserv`

Comment: yes. I did. but I didn't know where to put that command "insserv"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another option is to install bumblebee and copy the install-files/bumblebee-disablecard-on-powerup into /usr/local/bin with your OFF method.