# SABnzbdplus will not start on boot but running the init.d script runs fine

Tags: init.d

I am running the Ubuntu 12.04 server edition (static LAN IP) and was tying to install SABnzbdplus using the apt as per instructions here:
[Ubuntu PPA Repository](http://wiki.sabnzbd.org/install-ubuntu-repo)

Installation has gone smoothly and the server downloads etc no problem! The problem is that I have edited /etc/default/sabnzbdplus as the directions provided to:

```
# This file is sourced by /etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus
#
# When SABnzbd+ is started using the init script, the
# --daemon option is always used, and the program is
# started under the account of $USER, as set below.
#
# Each setting is marked either "required" or "optional";
# leaving any required setting unconfigured will cause
# the service to not start.

# [required] user or uid of account to run the program as:
USER=omar

# [optional] full path to the configuration file of your choice;
#            otherwise, the default location (in $USER's home
#            directory) is used:
CONFIG=

# [optional] hostname/ip and port number to listen on:
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=8080

# [optional] extra command line options, if any:
EXTRAOPTS=
```

My (omar) runlevel is N 2.

Not quite sure what to do because executing:
/etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus
Works fine and error free.

Not sure what to do here. Advice and assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The guide forgot

```
sudo update-rc.d sabnzbdplus defaults
```

This command will add the links at the correct runlevels so that sabnzbdplus starts and stops when booting, rebooting, shutting down, etc.

edit: if you get the message that those links are already in place have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177589/services-in-rc-d-not-starting-automatically-at-boot) question

edit2: or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9763/init-d-script-startup-problems) one

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I just switched to Debian and all works well.

Comment: Oh that's too bad, glad you got it working though!