# Services in rc.d, not starting automatically at boot

Tags: startup

I have a few services in rc.d that aren't starting at boot time. I've done the update-rc.d, redoing it tells me that start/stop links are already in place, and I can start services manually by using service start.

One of these services (sabnzbdplus) was pulled from apt, the others are downloaded from git. None of them start up automatically.

Nothing seems to be on google other than reinstall the whole system. Any advice?

Comment: Notably, this is using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected this problem by chuser'ing the files/directories that were involved (including settings). I believe this happened because starting and stopping services with sudo gives them root privileges, whereas they're run as the user account at startup.

Comment: can you elaborate this? I'm struggling!!

Comment: Please can you give detail steps. My system suddenly started this issue for 2 scripts.

Answer (score -1):

A folder and subsequent files in 'nix are owned/operated by users+ groups + everyone else. When root owns a folder/files in that folder, only root can use those folder/files for any purpose unless permission is given to others to use those same folder/files.

In this case, the scripts are owned by root so any user will not be able to run them unless two things happen. 1) either root allows anybody else to run them by changing permissions to something like 777 (read, write and execute by anyone) or 2) including the user in the same group with root thereby allocating those same rights to the user.

Both are not the same however. 1 gives all users the right to use (maybe dangerous) whilst ownership stays with root but 2 shares ownership with user through inclusion in same group (exposure to only one user may be more manageable).

I tend to use 1 but that is personal preference and also cos I'm lazy as running one script like "sudo chmod -R 777 /etc/init.d/couchpotato" solves my problems (note my system is isolated so it works for me whereas 2 may be the best solution for open or not so closed systems.
Hope that helps someone else

Comment: 1) How is this related to the question? 2) What's the purpose of giving everybody write permission on system daemon start files? -1

Comment: Sorry. late night, right answer to wrong question

Comment: I actually have had this problem and there area  couple of factors you should consider.

Comment: Sorry I was caught by the 5 min rule.