# Service not starting at machine boot up - Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 14.04, server, services, reboot, init.d

I created `Weblogic` server as a `service` to start at boot up of machine by creating weblogic file inside directory **`/etc/init.d/`** with below content:

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/default/weblogic

start() {
    nohup ${WLSHOME}/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh && ${WLSHOME}/common/bin/wlst.sh /opt/nmstart-${ADMINSERVER}.py
    for i in $SERVERS; do
    ${WLSHOME}/common/bin/wlst.sh /opt/start-"$i".py &
    done
}

stop() {
      ${DOMAINPATH}/bin/stopWebLogic.sh -username ${USER} -password ${PASSWORD}
}

case "$1" in
start)
    start
    ;;
stop)
    stop
    ;;
restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
esac
```

and another file with same name(weblogic) inside directory **`/etc/default/`** with content as follows:

```
# /etc/default/weblogic script used to configure the init script
WLSHOME="/opt/weblogic/wlserver_10.3"
DOMAINPATH="/opt/weblogic/projects/test"

# Username password for stopping
USER="weblogic"
PASSWORD="weblogic1"

# Servers to start
SERVERS="wlserver-1 wlserver-2 "
ADMINSERVER="AdminServer"
```

When I run the command `sudo service weblogic start`, server starts but on restarting the machine weblogic service not started.

Then, I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177589/services-in-rc-d-not-starting-automatically-at-boot) questions to make it work, but none of them works for me.

P.S: running the command `sudo update-rc.d weblogic defaults`, gives me output:

```
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/weblogic missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/weblogic already exist.
```

Any idea how can I make weblogic service to start at machine boot up?

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer to the problem and thought of sharing it for future readers, the problem is [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command used in the start block:

```
start() {
    nohup ${WLSHOME}/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh && ${WLSHOME}/common/bin/wlst.sh /opt/nmstart-${ADMINSERVER}.py
    for i in $SERVERS; do
    ${WLSHOME}/common/bin/wlst.sh /opt/start-"$i".py &
    done
}
```

At time of machine reboot, **nohup is ignored** making NodeManager script **`not to run as a background process`** which I can see in **`/var/log/boot.log`** file:

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

So, tweaking the start block to use [ampersand (&)](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/unix/reference/commands.html#amp) for **`running the NodeManager script in background instead of nohup`** worked, as follows:

```
start() {
        ${WLSHOME}/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh &
        ${WLSHOME}/common/bin/wlst.sh /opt/nmstart-${ADMINSERVER}.py
        for i in $SERVERS; do
        ${WLSHOME}/common/bin/wlst.sh /opt/start-"$i".py
        done
}
```